# How to restart network-manager without root password

Tags: 14.04, permissions, network-manager, services

My wireless is flaky so I'd like to be able to restart network-manager with a script WITHOUT having to type the root password.

I tried making a c program that does this:

```
setuid(0);
system("service network-manager restart");
```

And I set the permissions as follows:

```
sudo chown root:root suscript
sudo chmod 4755 suscript
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
stop: Unknown job: network-manager
start: Unknown job: network-manager
```

I guess something is wrong in the environment, but I don't know what. Can anyone help? Thanks.

By the way, this is xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: How about the commands `nmcli nm wifi off; nmcli nm wifi on`? `nmcli` doesn't require root access.

Comment: Or, in network manager, you can stop and start wireless. You probably do not need to restart network manager.

Comment: @muru, I will try this, but I suspect network manager bugs contribute to my wireless problems, so I have generally found restarting it to be more useful than working within it.

Comment: In which case, you could switch another tool like wicd.

Comment: Believe me, I have considered it...